# Console.log() OR getDocumentbyID in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This this beginner-level Javascript Exercise, I find 2 possible solutions for (see code below):

1. console.log();
2. document.getElementById("valueID").innerHTML = variablename;

What is the difference between printing the solution out in the console (F12) or via the DOM?
I understand that the `console.log();`is strictly for internal testing (for developers).
But when should I use the "document.getElementByID", is that for DOM manipulation?
And are there any other differences between these two, in terms of performance?

Thanks. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <title>Introduction</title>
</head>

<body>
   <h1>Introduction</h1>
   <p id="Name"></p>
   <p id="Surname"></p>
   <p id="Age"></p>

   <script>
       let name = prompt("Introduce your name: ");
       let surname = prompt("Introduce your surname: ");
       let age = prompt("Introduce your age: ");
       //TO PRINT OUT IN CONSOLE
       console.log(name + " " + surname + " " + age);

       document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = name;
       document.getElementById("Surname").innerHTML = surname;
       document.getElementById("Age").innerHTML = age;
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Console.log (); will write the result to the dev console (for testing only), document.getElementById is used to take / modify / interact with that element not only for print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.log as you said is use for the development , to check our variables' values but **it has no impact on the DOM** (page).

document.getElementById thing will change directly the DOM which allows you to **change the actual page and values of elements you decided.**

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: ok, thanks, Alexandre, so yes. That´s helpful. So, ```console.log();``` is internally and ```document.getElementById```is for DOM manipulation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the `console.log` if I want to check if something is working.
Sometimes my function is working but the translation into the DOM is not working.

If I would use the `getElementById`, I would not see if my function is working or if my DOM manipulation is working..

Hopefully this helps a little, I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: thanks, Blackdispute!                                                                                                           I was just wondering. Yeah, I know the console.log(); is really helpful for that. There are many experienced developers out here, who could probably guide us newbies:)

Comment: I'm glad they help us here haha, really need it sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log()` is a function that writes a message to log on the debugging console, such as Webkit or Firebug. In a browser you will not see anything on the screen. It logs a message to a debugging console.
It's not a jQuery feature but a feature for debugging purposes. You can for instance log something to the console when something happens.

The `document.getElementById()` method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value. And the `innerHTML` change the value of that specific element of mentioned **ID.**

`document.getElementById()` **modifies the DOM**, but `console.log()` does not read/ write/ modify/ update the DOM

Comment: Oh, Abhishek, yeah, your last sentence explains it perfectly! Thank you! Really clear now.